# Can replacing a T&P valve be done as DIY by a home owner?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, safety, gas

I want to replace the T&P valve on my gas water heater since it is dripping water all the time. I talked to a couple of people such as my friend and a salesperson at a Home Improvement Store. They said I need to call a professional to do the job. I researched the subject on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUIyc8yqZMg) and find it can be done by myself. I do not know the reason why I would need to call a professional, which is expensive. Can it be done by ourselves?

I know the basic safety procedures. For example, I need to shut off the water/gas and drain all the water to reduce the pressure in the tank before doing anything. Are there any other safety concerns? I mean if it too complicated I will call a professional but I want to make sure that I really need them.

Comment: I would rephrase the question to something like "How do I replace the T&P valve and what are the safety concerns?". My short answer is, yes, you can do it yourself, and you probably don't need a plumbing license (depending on where you live).

Comment: You are tampering with a safety device on a water heater, which could lead to property damage, injury, and potentially death.  Do you trust your plumbing knowledge and skills enough to do this job properly?

Answer (score 3):

#### *Can it be done*?

Probably.

#### *Should it be done*?

Maybe.

#### *Are you allowed to do it*?

Depends on your location.

Replacing the valve is fairly straight forward, and can be done following the instructions provided with the replacement valve.  The bigger problem is determining **why** the valve is leaking, and fixing that problem.

The purpose of the valve is to open if the temperature and/or pressure in the tank reaches or exceeds specific levels. My answer to a [previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/25221/33), provides more information about these situations. There is another common cause for leaking T&P valves, which may be more applicable to your situation.

## Gunk.

When a T&P valve is opened; either during testing of during a fault, *gunk* (corrosion, mineral deposits, etc) can become lodged in the valve. This *gunk* prevents the valve from closing properly, which can lead to leaks. If *gunk* is the problem, replacing the valve may be the only solution required.

If you're not sure why the valve is leaking, you're not comfortable working on hot water tanks (or plumbing in general), or you simply do not have the proper tools for the job. Please do not hesitate to contact a local licensed Plumber.