# What are the three copper connections to my water heater?

Tags: water, water-heater

Why do I have 3 copper pipes in my gas water heater?  It seems two are cold and one is hot. All videos I see online show only two pipes; one for cold coming in, one for hot going out.

Comment: A picture, or a few, would help immensely. You'll have to make links as a new user and someone will edit and embed them for you.

Comment: Can you provide the make and model of your water heater?

Comment: The third might be connected to the pressure/temp relief valve, in which case it should be going to a drain. This is good, because [if that valve discharges significantly](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/25221/157) and doesn't get to a drain, it can cause a flood.

Comment: gregmac is likely right, only other possibility I can come up with is a recirculation pump, but those tend to be attached to the cold water pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the specific system installation and type of tank it could be any of these:

1. Cold in, hot out, and overflow:  Standard water heater.
2. Cold in, hot out, recirculate in.  This configuration has diverse uses:

   - typical for a solar water heating booster.
   - In heavy use applications, it could be for an external hot water reservoir.
   - In long lines applications, this could be for recirculating hot water so that a faucet 400 feet away has hot water available just a few feet away.  Many motels and hotels are plumbed this way.